# Food processor for pizza dough

Tags: dough, pizza

I'm happy that the recipes for New York style pizza from Serious Eats and from ATK both use a food processor to make the dough. I'm giving those recipes a shot as soon as my baking stone arrives from Amazon. I have a request for homemade pizza from a neighbor who wants it *tomorrow* to eat while watching Nascar with a friend (OOOH! Look, he's turning left *again*!). So I'm looking at recipes that don't require a stone *or* 3 days in the fridge. I have found a few that look good, but alas, they ask for a stand mixer, which I currently don't have.

The one I'm most interested in is Grandma Pizza from Cook's Country (AKA ATK). It calls for:

> 3 tablespoons olive oil, 
>   3/4 cup water, 
>   1 1/2 cups (8 1/4 ounces) bread flour, 
>   2 1/4 teaspoons instant or rapid-rise yeast, 
>   1 teaspoon sugar, 
>   3/4 teaspoon salt.
>
> 1. Coat rimmed baking sheet with 2 tablespoons oil. Combine water and remaining 1 tablespoon oil in 1-cup liquid measuring cup. Using stand mixer fitted with dough hook, mix flour, yeast, sugar, and salt on low speed until combined. With mixer running, slowly add water mixture and mix until dough comes together, about 1 minute. Increase speed to medium-low and mix until dough is smooth and comes away from sides of bowl, about 10 minutes.
> 2. Transfer dough to greased baking sheet and turn to coat. Stretch dough to 10 by 6-inch rectangle. Cover with plastic wrap and let rise in warm place until doubled in size, 1 to 1½ hours. Stretch dough to corners of pan, cover loosely with plastic, and let rise in warm place until slightly puffed, about 45 minutes.

Then it's topped and baked at 500F.

Will it work in the food processor too? If I mix it on the lowest possible speed (which is still much faster than the mixer) and give it a bit of hand kneading as soon as it comes away from the sides of the bowl?

Advice? Caveats?

Comment: I always use a food processor to make my pizza dough.  One important thing I will say, is that pizza dough really needs to [rise in the fridge overnight](http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/season3/pizza/pizzatranscript.htm) to ferment a little and get a good texture.

Comment: I've done the Serious Eats recipe with only an overnight rise.  It was enjoyed by all, and got compliments from someone who's a bit of a pizza snob.  I par cooked the crust in a cast iron skillet (both sides), then moved them to a sheet pan for people to top how they wanted, and finished in the oven.  (I was also cooking at high altitude ... Boulder, CO ... no idea how much that changes things)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frankly it should work fine.  As good or better than the mixer.  You probably won't need to do much by hand.  If you follow directions for food processor kneading for other doughs, then you should be totally good.  Do a windowpane test and a rest if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I've used a food processor for kneaded dough and it works pretty much the same as a stand mixer -- just faster. One thing to watch out for is that because the processor is so fast it can overheat the dough. I recommend cycling it to prevent overheating.